# How to add code highlighting to VuePress?

Tags: vuepress

VuePress seems to only support a handful of languages for doing syntax highlighting by default (also with the default theme).

The documentation mention "Line Highlighting" a lot, but that's a totally different feature to highlight a specific line within a code snippet. I'm looking for the ability to have syntax highlighting on a snippet of Scheme, or Java or PHP or others.

Out of the box, I only see support for JS, TypeScript, HTML, Markdown, JSON, Ruby, Python, Shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enable vuepress's syntax highlighting for one of the languages where it doesn't do highlighting by default, you need to add a CSS rule for that language.

In `.vuepress/style.styl`, add the following rule for scheme support:

```
div[class~=language-scheme]:before {
    content:"scheme"
}
```

Or the following for docker file support:

```
div[class~=language-docker]:before {
    content:"docker"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The VuePress out of the box is made by two parts: VuePress itself and its default theme.

VuePress itself handler the "syntax" part by using [prismjs](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/blob/58261c1ae3d101c2e512202b3b1edfacc10a645d/lib/markdown/highlight.js#L2). prismjs transform the markdown below

````
```SQL
SELECT column1
FROM table_name;
```
````

into the html below

```
<code>
    <span class="token keyword">SELECT</span>
    column1
    <span class="token keyword">FROM</span>
    table_name
    <span class="token punctuation">;</span>
</code>
```

You can find prismjs's supported languages at [here](https://prismjs.com/#languages-list).

I don't know the previous situation, but at least VuePress v0.14.2 supports all languages supported by prismjs.

The default theme handler the "highlighting" part by import [prismjs's css](https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/blob/58261c1ae3d101c2e512202b3b1edfacc10a645d/lib/default-theme/Layout.vue#L182) to color those token classes.